# Use polar coordinates to evaluate the integral

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

use polar coordinates to evaluate the following integral
$\int^{a}_{-a} \int^{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}_0 e^{-(x^2+y^2)}dydx$

i did in my paper was 
my limit are after converting it to polar coordinates 
$\int^{\pi}_0 \int^{{a}}_0 e^{-r^2}rdrd\theta$

Are the limits in the above integral true?

Comment: $x^2+ y^2= r^2$, not $r$.  Your integral should have $e^{-r^2}$ rather than $e^{-r}$.  Then use the substitution $u= r^2$.

Comment: Shouldnot the value be $x^2+y^2=a^2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The domain is a half-disk of radius $a$, on the side of the positive $y$.

In Cartesian coordinates, $x$ runs from $-a$ to $a$ and $y$ is between $0$ and $\sqrt{a^2-x^2}$ (where $x^2+y^2=a^2$).

In polar coordinates, $\theta$ runs from $0$ to $\pi$ and $r$ from $0$ to $a$.

---

In both cases,

$$x^2+y^2\le a^2\land y\ge0.$$

Indeed
$$x^2\le a^2\implies x^2+(a-x^2)\le a^2,$$

and

$$r^2\le a^2\land \theta\in[0,\pi]\implies\sin\theta\ge0.$$

Comment: yes thanks i exatly did it like this